# Items got error but I try to declare and use it and still got error

Tags: c#

Do please help me. I cant figure out why's the error...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Food");
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Items.Add(dir, i);
        i++;
        if (i == imageList1.Images.Count - 1)
            i = 0;
    }
}
```

> Error  1   'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why Items got error. My previous code it doesnt give me an error

Comment: [FlowLayoutPanel Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)  It doesnt have an items collection; it does have a Controls collection but it will not like you trying to add strings.  Dont imagine how things *might* work.

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel has a Controls property not an Items property, read the link above.

Comment: What do you mean @Plutonix ????

Comment: What gave you the idea it has an `Items` collection property?

Comment: Because I previously used in listview code... I'm sorry, I just learning c#... I'm not good at it...Please help me to make me learn it better...

Comment: A ListView is something entirely different than a FlowLayoutPanel so they have different properties and methods.  The link has everything you need.  Help yourself and enjoy

Comment: @Plutonix why don't you post your solution as an answer?